# Gentoo mounting root as read only, why?

Tags: gentoo, fstab

I just did a Gentoo fresh install but when I boot it the root filesystem mounts as read only. Once I login I can remount it with `mount -o remount,rw /` but it's not even recognizing my hostname. Someone on irc told me it could be that for some reason fsck bombs as root is always mount `ro` first and then `fsck` remounts it `rw`.

I found someone having the same problems and I tried what he did but it didn't work for me [Root file system is mounted read-only on boot on Gentoo Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/193115/root-file-system-is-mounted-read-only-on-boot-on-gentoo-linux)

This is my [fstab](http://bpaste.net/show/115514/).

**EDIT**
I already fixed it, it was a problem with an option not enabled in the kernel

```
Pseudo Filesystems --->
        [*] Virtual memory file system support (former shm fs)
```

Comment: Kind of a long shot because you can remount rw, but does `dmesg` mention IO errors?

Comment: Are you seeing any errors on boot? What does the output of `blkid` look like?

Comment: Please add the solution as answer, and accept it, so everyone knows your problem is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this solution over on SuperUser titled: [Root file system is mounted read-only on boot on Gentoo Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/193115/root-file-system-is-mounted-read-only-on-boot-on-gentoo-linux), which sounds exactly like your issue. The solution was to make sure that the `root` service was enabled in your boot runlevel. These are the services that were suggested as needing to be started in the boot runlevel:

```
bootmisc
consolefont
device-mapper
dmcrypt
fsck
hostname
hwclock
keymaps
localmount
modules
net.lo
netmount
network
procfs
root
svscan
swap
sysctl
sysfs
termencoding
urandom
```